# Bitwise operation c# array elements(0-1) transferring to integer

Tags: c#, arrays, bit-manipulation, 32-bit

we have an int array which contains random 32 numbers(1 and 0's ) and we need to transfer it to an integer number with bitwise how can i do that with bitwise operation

i did it without bitwise with using Math.Pow(2, j) method but how to make it with bitwise ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "bitwise" - it sounds like you have one solution but for some reason don;t want to use it.

Comment: double num = 0;
            Array.Reverse(numbers);
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[j] == 1)
                    num= num + (Math.Pow(2, j));
            }

   numbers is my array which one filled by 0-1 randomly 32 bits totally i want to transfer it to an integer number with bitwise operations or&and shifting or whatever i didnt get how to do it i should do transferring operation with bitwise not with mathpow

Comment: Good thing you asked, I see that pow hack too often..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use left-shift operator (`<<`), you can do something like this:

```
int number = 0;
int[] bits = new int[32];

for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    number |= bits[i] << i;
```

`<<` operator works like `Math.Pow(2, j);`

Comment: thanks its like that i guess